# How to read updated data in a stored procedure called multiple times simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

There are 2 tables:

- Wallets;
- Transactions.

There is a stored procedure that handles (I think with ACID operation):

- updating on Wallet table
- inserting one row into Transactions table
  every time it is called.

The issue occurs when there are many calls to the SP at same time, infact the value of PreviousBalance is not correct (sequentially wrong), cause in the SP read old value, meantime another process of call is running.

To understand better look the following screenshot.

There are 3 Transaction with same DT (IDs 1289, 1288, 1287), in all of those PreviouseBalance is equal, but is not correct, because the value for :

- Trx ID 1288 should be 180,78 as Balance of previous row;
- Trx ID 1289 should be 168,07 = 180,78 - 12,08

[image]

I think that the issue is in the SET of @OLDBalance var; at same time those 3 thread read same value, so when the SP goes to INSERT loads same value of PreviousBalance.

How can I do in order to read @OLDBalance correct after commit of one operation?
I tried to set several type of Isolation Levet into SP, the result was the same and sometime went in error for deadlock.

I have the following stored procedure:

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[upsMovimenta_internal]
    @AccountID int, 
    @Amount money, 
    @TypeTransactionID int, 
    @ProductID int, 
    @notes nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @OLDBalance MONEY;
    DECLARE @PreviousBalance MONEY;
    DECLARE @CurrentBalance MONEY;

    DECLARE @Molt float;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = @AccountID) 
    BEGIN
        RaisError(N'Account not found ', 10, 1, N'number', 3);
        return (1)
    END

    SELECT @Molt = Moltiplicatore 
        FROM TypeTransactions 
            where TypeTransactionID = @TypeTransactionID
    ;

    IF (@Molt is null )
    BEGIN
        RaisError(N'Error transaction', 10, 1, N'number', 3);
        return (1)
    END

    SET @Amount = @Amount * @Molt;

    --SELECT * FROM Wallets
    SELECT TOP 1 @OLDBalance = TotalAmount 
        FROM Wallets 
        where AccountID = @AccountID
        ;

        SET @CurrentBalance = @OLDBalance + @Amount;
        
        IF (@ProductID = 1 )
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Wallets
                    SET TotalAmount+=@Amount, 
                        Cash+=@Amount
                FROM Wallets where AccountID = @AccountID
                ;
        END

        IF (@ProductID = 2 )
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Wallets
                    SET TotalAmount+=@Amount, 
                        Fun+=@Amount
                FROM Wallets where AccountID = @AccountID
                ;
        END

        INSERT INTO Transactions  
             ( AccountID, ProductID, DT, TypeTransactionID, Amout, Balance, PreviousBalance, Notes )  
             VALUES
             ( @AccountID, @ProductID, GETDATE(), @TypeTransactionID, @Amount, @CurrentBalance, @OLDBalance, @notes)
        ; 

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    return (0)

END
```

Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, one way of managing locks on records, is to apply a dummy update on the rows you want to work on, right after starting transaction.

In this case SQL Server guarantees that those rows will be locked and no other transactions can access the rows. So you can change your design to something like this:

```
begin tran

update myTable 
set Field1 = Field1
where someKeyField = 212

-- do the same for other tables that you want to protect against change

-- at this moment all working rows will be locked, other procedure calls will be on hold

-- do your main operations here

commit tran
```

**The issue with this will be the other proc calls will wait and this may degrade performance or even time-out if the traffic is high and your operation in this proc is lengthy**

If you are working on high transaction environment, you need to change your design.

**Update: Design Suggestion**

I don't get why you have `PreviousBalance` and `Balance` in your transaction (it is against the design rules, however you can override rule in special case).

Probably you have that to speed up your calculations or make your queries simpler. But it is not good practice in OLTP database.
Rules say you keep the `Amount` column and calculate `PreviousBalance` and `Balance` somewhere else.

You should drop `PreviousBalance` but keep the `Balance` column, and every time you insert a transaction, you update (increase/decrease) the `Balance` column. **Plus you need to initialize the `Balance` column at the first transaction.**

This is what I can think of. If I knew your whole system, I would be able to have better ideas though.

Comment: great @FLICKER many thanks... 

Yesss! To get correct previuosbalance It was enough insert, in stored procedure, after begin transaction, an update statement of Wallets (even without changes actually). 

BTW, then I tried to insert "WAIT FOR" in SP to simulate delay for processes and actually with many operations I'm getting timeout exception. 
Can you give me good advices on which technic I can adopt, please? Thx

Comment: maybe the waitfor parameter is too big. I never used it but I guess if it is bigger than query timeout setting in your connection, you'll get timeout error. try smaller value for waitfor

Comment: also refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 for more detail. look at the "Caution" section

Comment: I put WAITFOR statemente in SP  to simulate other processes, so  for test it better in critical situation with simultaneous calls... 
Now, I'd like to avoid timeout or deadlok. 
You said of another technic or desing  "you need to change your design" ... I'd like to know which would be better in your opinion, please. Many Thanks